# Directx9: Reset Device after Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: c++, directx, device, direct3d, directx-9

I'm jusing a borderless Window and copied the device reset code from a Youtube video and it worked there but I just get the message from there:

```
if(FAILED(hr)){
    MessageBox(0, "Failed to reset device!", 0, 0);
    return;
}
```

Where did I something wrong? Did I forget something at `InvalidateDeviceObjects()`? I can give you more code but not everything because it's just too long.
I really need help... 

**Reset Device:**

```
void Render(){

if(HandleDeviceLost/*VK_F1*/){
    if(DeviceLost){
        Sleep(100);
        if(FAILED(hr=d3ddev->TestCooperativeLevel())){

            if(hr==D3DERR_DEVICELOST){
                return;
            }
            if(hr==D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET){

                //clean
                InvalidateDeviceObjects();

                //reset device
                hr=d3ddev->Reset(&d3dpp);

                if(FAILED(hr)){
                    MessageBox(0, "Failed to reset device!", 0, 0);
                    return;
                }

                //restore
                RestoreDeviceObjects();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
DeviceLost=0;

/*
   Stuff
*/

hr=d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(hr==D3DERR_DEVICELOST){
    DeviceLost=1;
}
}
```

**Release Objects:**

```
void InvalidateDeviceObjects(){

    buffShipMaterial->Release();
    Wall_large->Release();
    Wall_small->Release();
    space_text->Release();
    meshWall->Release();
    menuText->Release();
    menuText2->Release();
    menuText3->Release();
    text_cpu->Release();
    text_player->Release();
    text_player2->Release();
    number_0->Release();
    number_1->Release();
    number_2->Release();
    number_3->Release();
    number_4->Release();
    number_5->Release();
    number_6->Release();
    number_7->Release();
    number_8->Release();
    number_9->Release();
    number_10->Release();
}
```

Comment: I've had this on XP when switching users or locking screen - it seemed to be a driver problem and the only fix was to tear down and rebuild the whole DX9 system as if on application start. Similar systems with different gfx cards were ok.

Comment: I guess it's something in the code because I tried (downloaded) a simple game with device resetting and it worked.

Comment: So you have the source code for this simple game that worked? If so, you can compare. The only thing I can see is that if the first `Reset` fails, it's normal to `InvalidateRect` to get another repaint so you try again.

Comment: I compared it and I can't see any diference. It's the third there: http://www.codesampler.com/dx9src/dx9src_6.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample you linked that works, an error on `Reset` results in `return` and the `render` function just gets called again. This is normal - there is no reason why `Reset` must succeed on the first call, so it's usual to keep retrying rather than showing an error message like in your code.

If you're rendering in the message loop, like in that example, just do the same thing - don't stop when you get an error.

If you don't render in the message loop, but use the `WM_PAINT` method, then this is the general pattern that I use - although sometimes I set a timer rather than calling `InvalidateRect`, it depends on the app - but this has been robust enough for many applications. You can see how the `Reset` will get repeated on failure, rather than throwing an error message on the first fail. It might be an idea to adopt this pattern:

```
void CMyClass::DrawScene()
{
    // perform all dx9 scene drawing
    HRESULT hr;

    // if device was lost, try to restore it
    if (m_bDeviceLost)
    {
        // is it ok to render again yet?
        if (FAILED(hr = m_pD3DDevice->TestCooperativeLevel()))
        {
            // the device has been lost but cannot be reset at this time
            if (hr == D3DERR_DEVICELOST)
            {
                // request repaint and exit
                InvalidateRect(NULL);
                return;
            }

            // the device has been lost and can be reset
            if (hr == D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET)
            {
                // do lost/reset/restore cycle
                OnLostDevice();
                hr = m_pD3DDevice->Reset(&m_pD3Dpp);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    // reset failed, try again later
                    InvalidateRect(NULL);
                    return;
                }
                OnResetDevice();
            }
        }

        // flag device status ok now
        m_bDeviceLost = false;
    }

    // ... clear to background and do the drawing ...

    // display scene
    hr = m_pD3DDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);
    m_bDeviceLost = (hr == D3DERR_DEVICELOST);

    // request repaint if device has been lost
    if (m_bDeviceLost) 
    {
        InvalidateRect(NULL);
    }
}
```

Also, you must ensure that `TestCooperativeLevel` and `Reset` are called from the same thread that was used to create the device.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it failed the reset and crashed at the 2nd InvalidateDeviceObjects()/OnLostDevice(). I added something to use InvalidateDeviceObjects()/OnLostDevice() just one time(wrong?) but then it just fails every Reset. I don't use Threads.

Comment: Is there a list or something of what to ->release()/delete or ->onlostdevice()? I don't use textures, fonts or sprites. Just Meshes and Light.

Comment: @Vider7CC Yes, quoting [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174425(v=vs.85).aspx) - *"Calling IDirect3DDevice9::Reset causes all texture memory surfaces to be lost, managed textures to be flushed from video memory, and all state information to be lost. Before calling the IDirect3DDevice9::Reset method for a device, an application should release any explicit render targets, depth stencil surfaces, additional swap chains, state blocks, and D3DPOOL_DEFAULT resources associated with the device."*.

Comment: Now I'm recreating the device instead of resetting it and it works. Is there anything bad about this method?

Comment: @Vider7CC Well, now we come back to my first comment on your question. This sounds similar to what I had to do - the `Reset` call started returning `DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR` and there was no way back except by recreating the device. It feels overkill, but it works. You could try a driver update to see if that affects anything.

Comment: Thanks but I can't understand why it doesn't affect other games. I quess I will do something like using Reset() and after 5 fails recreating the device.I got a second problem by recreating the device:

Comment: @Vider7CC Yes, if it's similar to my problem, it depended on the types of resources I was releasing and restoring in the reset cycle. Using the managed pool helped, but it wasn't possible for everything.

Comment: /*Oh pressed return...*/ In the main menu works everything fine but ingame the objects are grey for a very short moment. (just ambient light?) Maybe because the ingame render function is larger? What could I do to solve it?

Comment: @Vider7CC I think we're now off-topic for your original question. Perhaps you should proceed as far as you can and ask separately for assistance. At the moment, chatting in comments doesn't highlight your problem to other SO users, who might have better answers than me.